# Migrating express-graphql to apollo-server v2

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to switch out express-graphql to apollo-server v2 but I'm having difficult time migrating packages, especially with passportjs and session.

My current set up with express-graphql:

```
const schema = include('schema')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  name: 'sessionId',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({ schema }))

const server = http.createServer(app)

server.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0', () =>
  console.log('Server running on port 8000')
)
```

And now with apollo-server-express@rc:

```
const schema = include('schema')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  name: 'sessionId',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

const apollo = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: ({ req: { user, session } }) => ({ user, session })
})
apollo.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' })

server.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0', () =>
  console.log('Server running on port 8000')
)
```

With this, I'm getting `user` and `session` objects in context and works like before but when I try to `login()` or `logout()` users via `context` it says `login is not a function`.

Ok so in context, `context: ({ req: { user, session, login, logout } }) => ({ user, session, login, logout })` and try again, but now I'm getting `Passport is not initialized`

Before I didn't have to set context with express-graphql so that's where I'm stuck. Please help?

Comment: I had a similar issue, but with using Hapi. Have you looked at the Test in Apollo-Server branch 2? https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/version-2/packages/apollo-server-express/src/expressApollo.test.ts